# porting PreferencePane to Lion [NSTextField getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: problem

Tags: nstextfield, nspreferencepane

I have a PreferencePane that works on Snow Leopard and we are getting ready for Lion. PreferencePane fails to load and gives me the following error in the Console. Note that it refers to 3 NSTextField instances (reports the same error twice per NSTextField).

I have way more than three NSTextFields in the preference pane. This happens after initWithBundle: completes successfully but before mainViewDidLoad.

`4/27/11 10:41:07.713 AM PreferencePane: -[NSTextField getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x40045ca20
4/27/11 10:41:07.714 AM PreferencePane: -[NSTextField getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x40045ca20
4/27/11 10:47:06.169 AM PreferencePane: -[NSTextField getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x40042d4c0
4/27/11 10:47:06.170 AM PreferencePane: -[NSTextField getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x40042d4c0
4/27/11 10:47:52.425 AM PreferencePane: -[NSTextField getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4004628a0
4/27/11 10:47:52.428 AM PreferencePane: -[NSTextField getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4004628a0`

Comment: Note that Lion is still under Non-Disclosure Agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Issue was that I had an NSTextField with variable name 'identifier'; while 10.6 didn't have any problem with it, 10.7 does. From some reason XCode on Lion didn't even warn me about it...